# Distortion of graphene structure

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

What is the effect of rolling a graphene sheet into a carbon nanotube on the lattice constant and the geometry of the graphene?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube) for the carbon nanotube yet?